# Creating setup for windows 10 machine using visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-hosting

I have tried to create a setup file for a web application using Visual Studio 2010. When I tried to install the setup in windows 10 machine, I recieve the error message as

> **This setup requires IIS 5.1 or higher and windows xp or higher.**
>
> **This setup cannot be installed on windows 2000**
> **Please install IIS or a newer OS and run the setup again**

Is there any solution to overcome this scenario? I want to know whether this can be done using VS2010 or not? What is the best alternative if the answer is *NOT*?

Answer (score 0):

Do waht most sensible installer people do - forget the idiotic behavior the (way long retired) vs included stuff does.

Use WIX / the WIX toolset (http://wixtoolset.org/)

THAT SAID: 2010 is ancient and you really should consider at one point going to a SUPPORTED VERSION of visual studio. Can not even say whether WIX is supported on a THAT ancient version of Visual Studio. Time to upgrade - particularly as it will likely be free for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you're using the ClickOnce / Publish / vdproj or similar.
There is a "LaunchCondition" check in the vdproj file / deployment project which checks for the IIS version.

This link guides you to the location for some set-ups and has some useful ideas:
https://secureinfra.blog/2014/06/11/getting-error-this-setup-requires-internet-information-server-5-1-or-higher-and-windows-xp-and-higher-when-installing-setup-project-on-windows-server-2008-and-iis-7/

I found mine in the .vdproj file

The location of the IIS version in the registry has moved, so I changed my coding to:

```
"Condition" = "8:IISMAJORVERSION >= \"#10\""
```

and the RegKey to search for IISMAJORVERSION as:

```
"RegKey" = "8:SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\InetStp"
```